# Valor máximo separado en rango de horas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ventas
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    Prod NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CANTIDAD DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL,
    PRECIO MONEY  NOT  NULL,
    COSTO MONEY NOT NULL,
    VENTA INT NOT NULL,
    TS DATETIME NOT NULL,
    LINEA NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CAJA NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CAJERO NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Necesito saber a qué hora del día se compran más artículos por venta, y debo dividir el día en 3 bloques.

Saqué la información sobre la primer venta es a las 6:00 y la ultima es a las 22:00, dividí el dia en tres bloques como Bloque 1 de 6:00 a 11:00, el Bloque de 12:00 a 17:00 y el Bloque 3 de 18:00 a 22:00, entonces hice la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 DATEPART(HOUR, ts) AS [Bloque 1]
FROM Ventas
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, ts) <= 11
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, ts) > 6
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, ts)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Necesito saber como hacer los 3 bloques pero en un solo registro, ese es mi problema

Comment: Cuál sería tu resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia SQL es un poco larga porque lo dividí en etapas lógicas. Pero el rendimiento debería ser bueno, ya que, aunque parezca un poco complejo, solo va a leer los datos de la tabla una vez.

```
;with grupos as (
  select datepart(hour, ts) as hora,
         count(*) as num_ventas
    from Ventas
   group by datepart(hour, ts)),
grupos_con_bloque as (
  select hora,
         case when hora between 6 and 11 then 1
              when hora between 12 and 17 then 2
              when hora between 18 and 22 then 3
          end as bloque,
         num_ventas
   from grupos
  where hora between 6 and 22),
grupos_con_rank as (
  select hora,
         bloque,
         row_number() over (partition by bloque order by num_ventas desc) as rn
    from grupos_con_bloque)
select max(case when bloque = 1 then hora end) as [Bloque 1],
       max(case when bloque = 2 then hora end) as [Bloque 2],
       max(case when bloque = 3 then hora end) as [Bloque 3]
  from grupos_con_rank
 where rn = 1
```

Por supuesto, me imagino que técnicamente es posible que más de una `hora` por bloque compartan el mismo máximo número de ventas. En ese caso, es indeterminado cuál `hora` es escogido por el query.  Si deseas controlar la `hora` que se deba escoger en caso de empate, es posible hacerlo modificando el `order by` en la función `row_number()`.

Por ejemplo, si en caso de empate deseas escoger la `hora` mas baja, la modificación sería:

```
...
row_number() over (partition by bloque order by num_ventas desc, hora) as rn
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un `case` en el `select`

```
select top 1 datepart(hour, ts) as [Bloque 1]
  Case 
    when datepart(hour, ts)<=11 and datepart(hour, ts)>6 then venta 
    else 0 
  end as bloque1
  Case 
    when datepart(hou,ts)>11 and datepart(hour,ts)<=17 then venta 
    else 0 
  end as [Bloque 2] from ventas 
group by datepart(hour, ts)
```

Perdona no colocarlo completo en el celular es complicado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar "CASE"

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Seria mejor que agregaras un ejemplo de uso con la consulta de la pregunta

Comment: podrías aclarar un poco mas la solución?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una consulta con subconsultas, una subconsulta para cada bloque. Algo más o menos así haciendo uso de tu consulta:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(HOUR, TS) AS [BLOQUE 1]
    FROM VENTAS
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, TS) <= 11
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, TS) > 6
    GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, TS)
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) AS bloque1
,(
    SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(HOUR, TS) AS [BLOQUE 1]
    FROM VENTAS
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, TS) <= 12
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, TS) > 17
    GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, TS)
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) AS bloque2
,(
    SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(HOUR, TS) AS [BLOQUE 1]
    FROM VENTAS
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, TS) <= 22
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, TS) > 18
    GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, TS)
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) AS bloque3
```